# Migrating Routes to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am about to migrate my rails 3 application to rails 4.

There are some additional routes on my ressources that make some problems.
I get an error message for this lines in my route file:

```
resources :teams do
...   
   get 'apply' => 'teams#apply_membership', as: :apply_membership
   post 'apply' => 'teams#apply_membership_save', as: :apply_membership
...
```

This is the generated error message

```
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

In rails3 it was possible to define a get and a post route using the same alias and routing them to different controler methods.

Can I do this in rails4, too?
And if yes, how does it have to look like in my route file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not take two route name with same name. but you have done it. so please change,

```
get 'apply' => 'teams#apply_membership', as: :apply_membership
post 'apply' => 'teams#apply_membership_save', as: :update_membership
```

Take a look here for rails routings. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html